# If 'shone' is a verb here, why is it modified by 'gentle' rather than 'gently'?

Tags: adverbs, suffixes, parts-of-speech

What is the function of the word 'shone'and 'gentle' in the following sentences taken from *Witches' Loaves* written by O. Henry and Dylan Thomas's poem? Why is 'gentle', an adjective, used in this sentence? if 'shone' is a verb, why didn't he use 'gently' instead to modify the verb? In other words, when 'kindly' is used as an adverb, why didn't the author use 'gently'?

> "How gentle and kindly his eyes shone behind his spectacles!"

–  O. Henry

> "Do not go gentle into that good night"

– Dylan Thomas

Comment: _Shine_ is one of those verbs that has divergent transitive and intransitive stems. Transitive causative _shine_ is a regular verb: _shine, shined, shined,_ whereas intransitive stative _shine_ is irregular: _shine, shone, shone_. For instance, _He shined his boots until they shone brightly_.

Comment: Why O.Henry used and adjective, gentle, and not an adverb instead ,that is 'gently', to modify it? Why didn't he use 'gently'?

Comment: Or, for instance in the "Do not go gentle into that good night". Why not 'gently'? In other words, when  'kindly' is used as an adverb, why didn't the author use 'gently'?

Comment: *Gentle* is not an adjective. It is only a word. It can be ***used*** as a noun, as a verb, as an adjective, and as an adverb. *“One you’ve **gentled** the  stallion, the fine **gentles** need no longer speak **gentler** to him than to the **gentle** mare.”*

Comment: I'd think "how gentle" is acting as an adverbial phrase. "How calm he spoke!", "how slow he walked!" etc.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's the past tense of the verb *shine.*

For both sentences, it may be relevant that in some cases, people use the plain form of an adjective as an adverb rather than using the form with *-ly.* Note also that *kindly* can be used adjectivally as well as adverbially.

For the first sentence, I see another potential explanation, although I'm not sure how well it fits. Unfortunately, I can't find a dictionary that mentions this, but the verb *shine* can be followed by an adjective in certain cases. For example, we can say "his eyes shone red" or "her eyes shone bright."

Answer (score 2):

There's generally no answering the question of why a poet chose a particular locution. (Here it's Dylan Thomas, not O. Henry) But the *OED* finds that the use of *gentle* as an adverb, particularly in the comparative, goes back to Shakespeare.